# Copy file to same directory with appended filename Via SSH Bash Script

Tags: bash, ssh, scripts

How would I copy a batch of files into the same directory with an appended filename via SSH Bash Script?
For example.

/path/files/file /path/files/file-20120105

The trick is for it to be a one liner so I don't have to do any fancy for loop or some other mechanism to pass it via ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
cp /path/files/file /path/files/file-$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

To do the same for multiple files e direcories:

```
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d)
for f in /path/files/*; do
    cp -a "$f" "$f-$timestamp"
done
```

Comment: Can this be used for multiple files and directories? for example:
`cp /path/files/* /path/files/*-$(date +%Y%m%d)`

Comment: @JDCar: not so simple, see modified answer.

Comment: How do I pass that via an SSH Session?
`ssh user@server timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d); for f in /path/files/*; do; cp -a "$f" "$f-$timestamp"; done;`

Comment: You could do: `ssh user@server bash -c 'timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d); for f in /path/files/*; do cp -a "$f" "$f-$timestamp"; done'`.

Answer (score 0):

I would give **scp** (secure copy) a try:

From server to local:

```
scp -r username@server:folder/foldertocopy destination
```

From local to server:

```
scp -r foldertocopy username@server:folder/destination
```

Check `man scp` for extra options.